Calculating the pdf of the sum of dependent random variables, $X+Y$, given the pdf of the difference, $X-Y$, and marginals, $X$ and $Y$.
I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and want to compute the sum $Z=X+Y$. I know the traditional approach is to compute the following
$$
p_{Z}(z) = \int p_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\,dx 
= \int p_{X}(x)\,p_{Y\mid X}(z-x \mid x)\,dx
$$
I have access to both the marginal and conditional distribution required, however the distributions are nonlinear transformations of the normal distribution so this integral can't easily be computed. For greater clarity on the form of the distributions, I know $U=f(X)$ and $V=g(Y)$ where
$$
p_{U,V}(u,v) = N\left(\begin{bmatrix}u\\ v\end{bmatrix}\; \right| \; \left.\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix}I &\rho I\\ \rho I & I\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
Both $f$ and $g$ are invertible so by change of variables, I know that
$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y) = N\left(\begin{bmatrix}f(x)\\ g(y)\end{bmatrix}\; \right| \; \left.\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}I &\rho I\\ \rho I & I\end{bmatrix}\right) 
\cdot |\det(\nabla_xf(x))| 
\cdot |\det(\nabla_yg(y))|
$$
Due to these nonlinear transformations, I am unable to compute the integral required for the sum. However, I do have access to the distribution of the difference of the two variables $W=X-Y$.
$$
p_W(w) = N(h(w) \mid 0,I) \, \bigl|\det(\nabla_wh(w))\bigr|
$$
where $h$ is again some nonlinear, invertible function.

Is there a way to compute $p_Z(z)=p_{X+Y}(z)$ given the pdfs of $p_X(x)$, $p_Y(y)$, and $p_W(w)=p_{X-Y}(w)$?

I know that given just the marginal pdfs is not enough as they don't "give you" information about the dependence between the two variables necessary for the computation of the sums pdf, but intuitively, it feels like the pdf of the difference should "encode" this dependence so I am hoping that it might provide an easier approach to computing the sum. Thanks for any input and sorry for any clarity issues.

I  am pretty sure the pdf of $X+Y$ cannot be determined from the given data.

Bummer, I was hoping this wasn't the case. Do you have any intuition or counter-examples that you can think of for why it's not enough?
